# Conditional creation of Shapes - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, shapes

I am trying to write a function that creates a shape according to a specified condition but getting a compilation error.

```
func createShape() -> some Shape {
    switch self.card.shape {
    case .oval:
        return Capsule()
    case .rectangle:
        return Rectangle()
    case .circe:
        return Circle()
    default:
        return Circle()
    }
}
```

The error I am getting:

**Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types**

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605936/12299030?

Comment: I need the function `createShape` to return specifically a Shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of this [post](https://forums.swift.org/t/function-that-returns-any-shape-anyshape/35614/2), what helped me was:

Creating an `AnyShape`:

```
#if canImport(SwiftUI)

import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct AnyShape: Shape {
    public var make: (CGRect, inout Path) -> ()

    public init(_ make: @escaping (CGRect, inout Path) -> ()) {
        self.make = make
    }

    public init<S: Shape>(_ shape: S) {
        self.make = { rect, path in
            path = shape.path(in: rect)
        }
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { [make] in make(rect, &$0) }
    }
}

#endif
```

Then:

```
func createShape() -> AnyShape {
    switch self.card.shape {
    case .oval:
        return AnyShape(Capsule())
    case .rectangle:
        return AnyShape(Rectangle())
    case .circe:
        return AnyShape(Circle())
    }
}
```

Comment: In iOS16 here was introduce AnyShape struct. I have named your struct UniversalShape in case do not get compile problems.

Answer (score -1):

From the comment and link of Asperi:

Change to:

```
@ViewBuilder
func createShape() -> some View {
    switch self.card.shape {
    case .oval:
        Capsule()
    case .rectangle:
        Rectangle()
    case .circle:
        Circle()
    default:
        Circle()
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the function `createShape` to return specifically a Shape